# Embedding the Password in the Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scp

I am running a test script where files needs to be copied to the target embedded system.But when this command of copying the files to remote target system is run from the script I was prompted for the administrator password of the Target Board.How can I automate the script in such a way that the script will pick the password by itself(from within the script) and I don't have to put the password manually every-time i run the script.

Snippet form the script is as below :

```
scp test.file1 <Target ip-address>:/home/bot21/test/.

Password is prompted when the above command is run.
```

Comment: scp uses the SSH protocol under the hood. If you can SSH to that server without a password, it will work without prompting. Look into SSH keys and ssh-agent.

Answer (score 2):

The right way to do this is with key-based authentication.
[Read about it here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-ssh-key-based-authentication-on-a-linux-server).

If that link ever breaks, just google it: "ssh passwordless" or "ssh key authentication".  Despite Toby's comment, I think linking to or instructing how to search it yourself is better than repeating what others can say better and in more depth than I can.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sshpass` to pass the password to the `scp`. Something like

```
sshpass -p passw0rd scp test.file1 <Target ip-address>:/home/bot21/test/
```

But as already mentioned, using the keys is recommended. I added the following notes to SO Documentation before it was retired.

---

#### Connecting from script using password

When you really need to script `ssh` connection, piping the password into the `ssh` command does not work (`echo passw0rd | ssh host`). It is because the password is not read from standard input, but directly from TTY (teleprinter, teletypewriter, Teletype for historical reasons).

But there is `sshpass` tool which works around this problem. It can read the password from parameter, file or environment variable. But note that none of these options does not satisfy the security requirements for a passwords!

```
$ sshpass -p passw0rd ssh host
$ sshpass -f /secret/filename ssh host
$ SSHPASS=passw0rd sshpass -e ssh host
```

The command line options can be seen by other users in `ps` (during runtime it is masked, but not during start time and you can't rely on it):

```
... 23624  6216 pts/5    Ss   Aug30   0:00  \_ /bin/bash
... 12812  1988 pts/5    S+   08:50   0:00  |   \_ sshpass -p passw0rd ssh host
... 45008  5796 pts/15   Ss+  08:50   0:00  |       \_ ssh host
```

Note, that environemnet variables of a process are also accessible by other processes on the system using `/proc/PID/environ` file.

Finally, storing the password in the file might look like the best possible idea, but still using keys as described in the other examples is preferred way to use `ssh`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `-i` option. Manpage says:

> -i identity_file
>                Selects the file from which the identity (private key) for public
>                key authentication is read.  This option is directly passed to
>                ssh(1).

That is do :

```
scp -i /path/to/identity_file test.file1 <Target ip-address>:/home/bot21/test/
```

The process of creating the identity file is well described [[ here ]](https://linuxconfig.org/passwordless-ssh).

The access-permissions for the identity file should be configured in such a way that potential users in your system who may access this file should be able to read it. Also mind that these users should be able to traverse the path ie `/path/to` in our example to reach the file